# QByteArray of zero size; where do begin() and end() point to?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

QByteArray uses copy-on-write strategy, so copying them is cheap. I assumed that also means that it's okay to pass them by value.

However, this assumption seems to break when I use QByteArray with zero length:

```cpp
struct Frame 
{
  QByteArray load{0, 0}; // zero size, fill with zeroes
  QByteArray getLoad() { return load; }
};

Frame frame;
std::copy( frame.getLoad().begin(), frame.getLoad().end(), <somewhere> );
```

This sometimes produces SEGFAULT because `begin()` and `end()` seem to point in completely different locations, sometimes `end()` is numerically less then `begin()` (and that triggers debug verification check in MSVC about transposed pointers).

My current understanding is that's because `frame.getLoad()` constructs a temporary `QByteArray` twice, and for some reason iterators inside them point to completely different locations - if and only if array size is 0.
(I'm not sure where they *should* point if array size is zero and no memory is actually allocated but this still seems very surprising to me).

Is my understanding of this correct? If so - what should I do? Check for zero-sized edge case? Pass `QByteArray` by reference? Always construct proper lvalue array?

P.S. API returning `QByteArray` by value is not mine, it's from `QCanBusFrame->payload()`.

Comment: `frame.getLoad().begin()` and `frame.getLoad().end()` are iterators on two different objects.

Comment: Aha, it looks like `begin()` and `end()` can point at the reused array if the array has positive length, but there are no array to point when the length is zero, so some "random" (per object) value can be used for them.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, that's my point. Why do they use those random values instead of, say, nullptr?

Comment: If you try constBegin and constEnd, you will find that it "works". But.. is not recommended. You should save the return value in an intermediary variable ideally const, to avoid COW.

Comment: @Amomum As a rule, iterators to different containers are not compatible. Each copy of the container is a different container, even if there is a "copy on write" scheme implemented under the hood.

Comment: @Amomum Iterators are pointer-like but they are not pointers. It isn't always possible to implement a `nullptr` equivalent, and that concept isn't conceptually handled by iterators. Iterators represent invalid states by comparing equal to the `end` iterator of the same range, not strictly by their internal state. It isn't possible to check if an iterator, on its own, is valid or not, so the concept of `nullptr` isn't applicable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux sure, but QByteArray iterators are _actually_ pointers :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but you are right, of course; I just assumed that since copy is cheap and advisable, I can pretend that QByteArray is kinda like shared_ptr or span, and I assumed that iterators will always point to some 'common' storage. I was wrong indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `frame.getLoad()` twice in your call of `std::copy`. they will return different `QByteArray`, so their `begin()` and `end()` has no relation.

You can have `getLoad()` return the reference to `load` to overcome this problem.

```
QByteArray& getLoad() { return load; }
```

If you want `getLoad()` return the copy of `load`, you should store that to a variable before calling `std::copy` and use that.

```
Frame frame;
QByteArray frameLoad = frame.getLoad();
std::copy( frameLoad.begin(), frameLoad.end(), <somewhere> );
```

Answer (score 3):

"Copy On Write" implies that it is going *copy* before a *write*. Now, when you call `begin()` it returns you an iterator using which you can *write* to the container without the container knowing. So, what should the class do to avoid (possibly) invalidating shared state? It should *copy* the whole thing. That's what happens in your case. You get 2 copies, and iterators to different buffers.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds logical :)